# C Floating point zero comparison

Tags: c, floating-point, double, zero

Will the following code, with nothing in between the lines, always produce a value of `true` for the boolean `b`?

```
double d = 0.0;
bool b = (d == 0.0);
```

I'm using g++ version 4.8.1.

Comment: probably not, it's better to check whether distance to 0 is small enough.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this. It's perfectly fine to be paranoid about floating-point comparisons if you hang around this site enough.

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk: Floating-point does not insert changes without cause. Setting a value to zero results in a value of exactly zero, and comparing it to zero results in true.

Comment: **0.0** is exactly representable by standard IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point. Your compiler will initialize `d` with the exact value of **0.0**. However, if you do any calculations on `d` and later expect it to have a value of exactly **0.0**, then all bets are off.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Not all bets are off. Floating-point behavior within IEEE 754 is well specified; bets using IEEE 754 are definitely on, not off. Binding from C to IEEE 754 is only loosely specified, so there is some flexibility there. Bets made using good C implementations (with well-defined binding) are on, and careful bets made with lax C implementations are on.

Comment: Never use == for floating point formats: you will surely run into trouble.

Comment: @Michael: Oddly, in floating-point, `==` is an operation that **always** produces an exactly correct result given its inputs, unlike `+` or `*`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Err, what?! Double-precision != infinite precision. The second you start computing values of `d` you lose the guarantee that a series of operations that *should* on paper generate **0.0** ***will*** actually result in exactly **0.0**.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Betting that a calculation whose exactly mathematical result is zero has a computed result is zero is not the only bet one can make. You said all bets are off. My point is that is not the case. A bet that the computed value is the value specified by IEEE 754 is on, not off. You **can** use the rules of IEEE 754 to derive formal statements about the calculated values, and you **can** use those rules to design software to produce desired results.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: first of all, define "correct". The programmer's intention does not always coincide with **literal** meaning of floating point code: the programmer would assume that 0.3+0.2==0.5, but the floating point numbers in such code would mean something slightly different, and the equality "correctly" wouldn't hold. Second, == does **not** always produce correct result because on some processors, including the latest Intel CPUs, the operands may subtly alter their value when moved between registers and RAM.

Comment: @Michael: For `==`, the definition of correct is that the result is true if and only if the two input values are equal. Your example of `.3 + .2 == .5` is not a counter-example, because the error in this case occurs in the `+` operation, not in the `==` operation, as I stated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Except for the fact that IEEE 754 is not always strictly followed. Optimizing compilers will violate many of the rules, as will certain instructions in many ISAs, and some classes of processors such as GPUs support a different subset of the rules per-generation. Relying on those characteristics is a bad idea for portability.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: As I said, bindings to IEEE 754 are lax. However, not everybody writes for portability; there are hugely important applications that are not portable. Knowledge about writing good floating-point should be promoted, because it is useful. Furthermore, we should advocate for compilers to adhere to IEEE 754 (at least when requested by an option), so that we get the benefits of IEEE 754.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: take a look at my answer below, the comparison between hardcoded 0.2 and 0.2 that produces incorrect result. I did this experiment just now on CentOS running on Intel Xeon.

Comment: This question is tagged with C, but you say use are using g++, which is a C++ compiler (unless switches override the language). Which are you asking about, C or C++?

Comment: @Michael: Your experiment gets the behavior it does because operands of different values are provided to `==`, not because `==` returns an incorrect result. As I said, it is **other** operations that introduce rounding errors, not `==`. Your experiment involves three operations: Conversion of `.3` to a floating-point value (not necessarily a `double` value although `double` in nominal type), conversion of that value to `double`, and evaluation of `==`. The first two operations have rounding errors. The third does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Fair enough, I am chiefly concerned with portability for my work. I should have written that comment to indicate that the behavior could be different among different implementations. But as far as bets go in my original statement, the only bet I was referring to was that the value was exactly **0.0**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `IEEE-754` (and probably most floating point representations), this is correct as  `0.0` is representable exactly in all `IEEE-754` formats.

Now if we take another literal that is not representable exactly in `IEEE-754` binary formats, like `0.1`:

```
double d = 0.1;
bool b = (d == 0.1);
```

This may result in `false` value in `b` object!

The implementation has the right to use for example a `double` precision for `d` and a greater precision for the comparison with the literal.

> (C99, 5.2.4.2.2p8) "Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values of operations with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and        precision may be greater than required by the type."